# Meteor App Server Timeout

Tags: node.js, angular, meteor, timeout

How do we should handle timeout in the server side in a Meteor App? For example, if we call from the client Meteor.call('loadUsers'). Suppose this loadUsers function takes too long for any reason, what should happen? Is there any way to setup this timeout? How do i test it in development mode?

Comment: Check [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/best-way-to-time-out-a-meteor-method-call/8660/4) out.

Comment: This is adding a delay before the server return. What i want is, suppose the server is overloaded, it could take very long to return, the http connection has a timeout for example, how about the meteor timeout, what is it? How do i handle it?